# excel year() formula returns incorrect year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For some reason the Excel year() formula does not return **2008** as expected!

I am using Excel 2016 (offline version)

```
Row    C              D                     Formula
1      SourceDate     YearOnly
2      2008/12/01     1905/06/30            =YEAR(C2)
```

Comment: What does it return?  Two things to check; you are showing the date in Column C, I assume this is me misunderstanding the data.  Second are your "dates" true dates or are they text that look like date.

Comment: 1905/06/30 is the 2008th day after 1900/01/01. So your formula works correct. Simply don't format the 2008 as Date but as General.

Comment: Spot on Axel! Just came to that realisation too.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that the Year() formula returns a *Number*, however I had column D formatted as a *Date*

Changed this back to number and now I get the correct date as expected!

I also see that I can retain the Date format on column D but must then reconstruct a full date e.g. = Date(Year(C2),1,1)